# Geckodriver NOT recognized despite being in System PATH

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, geckodriver, system-paths

**Summary:** Geckodriver seemingly isn't recognized despite that it is accurately set in the SYSTEM PATH

**Current System Configuration:**

- Operating System: Windows 10; Version: 1909; OS build: 18363.752; System type: 64-bit OS
  [Windows System Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3sYz.png)
- Installed ***Microsoft Visual Studio redistributable
  runtime***: vc_redist.x64.exe
- User Environment Variable value: "C:\Users\PCUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\PCUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;%IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Development\Selenium Resources\Selenium Drivers\geckodriver.exe;C:\Development\Selenium Resources\Selenium Drivers\chromedriver.exe;C:\Development\Selenium Resources\Selenium Drivers\;C:\Development\Selenium Resources\Selenium Drivers;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;"
- System Environment Variable value: "%path%;C:\Development\Selenium Resources\Selenium Drivers;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Ruby26-x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin\javaw.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin;C:\Users\PCUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38;C:\Users\PCUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts;C:\Development\Selenium Resources\Selenium Drivers\;C:\Development\Selenium Resources\Selenium Drivers\chromedriver.exe;C:\Development\Selenium Resources\Selenium Drivers\geckodriver.exe;"
- Directory where Selenium Driver's are saved: ***C:\Development\Selenium Resources\Selenium Drivers***
  [Selenium Drivers Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5flpb.png)
- Firefox Browser Version Installed: 74.0 (64-bit)
- Geckodriver version installed: geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64.zip from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
- Github Project (up-to-date): https://github.com/cikent/Selenium-Projects/tree/master/Selenium-PythonProjects/python-webui-testing

**Objective/Goal:**
Resolve Geckodriver not being detected so I can continue setting up an Automation Framework in Python utilizing Selenium and Pytest by referencing the following Guide from Automation Panda: https://blog.testproject.io/2019/07/16/read-config-files-in-python-selenium/

**What have I already tried?:**

- Restart System after each update to Environment Variables
- Launching geckodriver from the Powershell Terminal, run: ***geckodriver***
- Ensured that had Microsoft Visual Studio redistributable installed to account for the following error called out here for Windows v0.26.0 (as mentioned above):

  - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
  - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
- Verified that my Github project executes just fine with the following command: ***pipenv run python -m pytest*** when my configuration file ***config.json*** has the ***browser*** parameter set to: ***chrome***
- Hour's of searching on Google, Stackoverflow, Reddit and beyond trying to troubleshoot why this isn't working... :(

**Actual Result:**
When I execute: ***pipenv run python -m pytest*** from the following directory: ***C:\Development\Selenium-Projects\Selenium-PythonProjects\python-webui-testing***, I get:
[PowerShell Execution of Pytest & Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80qm2.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not about geckodriver’s path. The problem is that “Firefox” cannot be found as a token in the Python code.

Add this import to the module with the config fixture: “from selenium.webdriver import Firefox”.

Comment: your comment just made me realize that i had commented out `import firefox` xD thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the webdriver_manager, so that you don't have to deal with all these issues. It's pretty simple as shown below. And the `webdriver_manager` will get th latest stable driver based on the Operating system and the architecure.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
# continue using the driver as usual.
```